# Monitor network usage of processes on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, networking, process

I am writing a script and a part of it specifically deals with monitoring processes and how much data they send through, basically their download speeds. I have found ways of checking your own network speeds using speedtest-cli however I can't find anything pertaining to monitoring data used by processses.

---

To be more specific, I need a way for my script (running on windows) to monitor the network usage of all processes and alert me when and which of them downloads more data per second than a set limit.

Any kind of help is very appreciated!

Comment: [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.